# Instant app not running on emulator

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have One instant app project, which after few hurdles I was able to run on the emulator (*Nexus 5X API 26*)

[Android: Instant app showing just white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817815/android-instant-app-showing-just-white-screen?noredirect=1#comment77592684_44817815)

Now, after 2 months I am trying to run the same project but its not working out

**Nexus 5X(Any api):**

`Adb devices` give the following result

`emulator-5554   unauthorized`
[image]

---

**Pixel APi 24 :**

Side loading failed with message: Failure when trying to read bundle.Unable to connect to Google Play services.
 **ConnectionResult**`{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}`

### [image]

**Physical Device's :**

Provision failed with message: The device used is not whitelisted for Instant Apps deployment.

As per doc's Instant apps work on

> [Most Android devices running Android 5.1 (API level 21) or higher.](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html)

Devices that I have tried on

- Mi Redmi Note 3(marshmallow)
- Moto G4 plus (Nougat)

---

**Android studio version 3**

How can it be made to work?

Comment: This seems like something with your android sdk may be off. You can try to either update or re-install it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: +1 to @Mustafa's answer for Pixel API 24, but not the other two.

The unauthorized error is from adb and is unrelated to Instant Apps. Make sure you enabled USB Debugging.

Re "Only few selected devices": Instant Apps are supported on "most Android devices running Android 5.1 (API level 21) or higher" ([source](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html#setup-emulator)).

Comment: @ philo there is no option to update google play services on Pixel Api 24

Comment: @philo instans apps are supported on most devices but you can develop on only few devices.

Comment: @Sunny Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Sunny, sorry, I meant that the diagnosis was correct, that Play Services was out of date. I should have confirmed the proposed fix before saying "+1". If you create a new emulator image (make sure your emulator is up to date in Android SDK Manager), it should have an updated Play Services. @Mustafa, do you have an example of a supported device where you can't do local development?

Comment: Only emulator Nexus 5/5X API 24-26 have Play Store included in its image, but I have been able to run instant apps on emulator Pixel API 24-26 as well. You may need to delete it, make sure your images are updated, and recreate the AVD.

Answer (score 1):

**Pixel API 24 emulator:**

1. You need to install an Android system image that have Google APIs. You can see those images while creating new emulator, they have a name like: "Android 7.1.1 **(Google APIs)**".
2. Make sure you have the latest version of Google Play Services in your emulator. To do that: go to **emulator's extended controls (by clicking three dots) -> Google Play -> Update**. Note that this only visible if you install a system image with Google APIs (see step 1.)
3. Make sure you enabled Instant Apps on your device/emulator. See: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en

---

**Physical Device:**

Only few selected devices (such as Pixel) are compatible with Instant Apps **development**.

See: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/issues/1

---

See the [developer documents](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html#setup-emulator) about setting up device or emulator for Instant Apps development.

Comment: Sorry, didn't put the question like that, but I have already tried everything you mentioned. Anyways edited my question with screenshots.

Comment: I have Pixel Api 24 device having target Android 7.0(Google Api's). But still extended menu dosen't have any option to update play services

Comment: Apparently emulator should also have Play Store. So right now you can use Nexus 5 or Nexus 5X. You can see the Play Store icon in de emulator device list. Can you try it with either one of them?

Comment: yeah, that's the issue only supported emulator is 5x which is again showing me unauthorized