# Unable to run instant app from android studio

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am unable to run my app in instant app mode, while if i run application module it works fine. But as i select instant app module it runs but white screen appears.

Created project by using built in instant app support of android studio

Following this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jg1D07NgeI&t=569s
and several blogs , code lab instruction and other tutorials on youtube

[image: project structure]
[image: app and base modules structure]

feature module is empty app module don't contain any activity only base module contains single activity

app : gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anilsharma92.myintantapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

base gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    application project(':app')
}

instant app gradle :

    apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anilsharma92.myintantapp.app">


</manifest>
```

base : manifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anilsharma92.myintantapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
            android:value="1" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPattern="/splash" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[asset json file](https://anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

Comment: Ah, what version of AS and what emulator setup are you using? There is something up with certain emulator setup(s) where the very last object to be rendered will appear blank/white. (shove a toast in the activity and you will see what I mean) So.. just use a different emulator setup.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817815/android-instant-app-showing-just-white-screen

Answer (score -1):

> Why are you including your app Module inside the base module?

`application project(':app')` - **it shouldn't!**

If there is part of code of the app, you want to use it inside the base module. You should create another module. A library module to contain you common part, this module will be include by the app and the base module.